# Entity framework inserting multiple tables - not inserting foreign key

Tags: entity-framework

I want to insert to two tables at the same time.

Code:

```
public void AddPaymentTransactions(List<CartItemModel> list, int customerId, decimal balance)
{
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        PaymentTransaction paymentTransaction = new PaymentTransaction();
        paymentTransaction.CustomerId = customerId;
        paymentTransaction.Amount = item.ItemTotal;
        paymentTransaction.OfferId = item.OfferId;

        // for each payment transaction we add transaction event
        Transaction transaction = new Transaction();

        transaction.CustomerId = customerId;
        transaction.Status = 1;
        transaction.Description = "Payment for <b>" + item.OfferName + "</b>";

        transaction.TransactionType = 1;
        transaction.Credit = item.ItemTotal;
        transaction.Balance = balance + item.ItemTotal;
        transaction.PaymentTransaction = paymentTransaction;

        this.ClientRepositories.LiveData.AddToPaymentTransactions(paymentTransaction);
        this.ClientRepositories.LiveData.AddToTransactions(transaction);
    }

    this.ClientRepositories.LiveData.SaveChanges();
}
```

DB:
[image]

As I understand I connect entity here:
transaction.PaymentTransaction = paymentTransaction;

And after paymentTransaction is commited it will automatically add foreign key to Transaction, but it doesn't.

Comment: Yes it should, but what happens in `LiveData`? (BTW I wouldn't store UI-specific display metadata in the database, i.e. the HTML tags).

Comment: LiveData is just proxy for web data service.

Comment: I don't understand. Since you use the tag "mvc" your code already looks like server-side code. What's the (base)type of `LiveData`?

Comment: It is server side. LiveData is proxy to web data service... it is proxy to entities.

Comment: What is the architecture of your program?  You are saying that you're using Entity Framework, and show code that invokes methods on this.ClientRepositories.LiveData, but say that LiveData is a pointer to a web service?  You need to show the code that the Web Service is invoking against EF.

Comment: its just insert ... does it really matter? its normal insert invoked by webservice proxy.. LiveData is db context. Example of insertion without webservice http://pastebin.com/5Tmfwpid